# How to make GCC help option (`--help=`) display help information about `-L` and `-l` options for specifying libraries?

Tags: debian, gcc, g++

I have found the GCC help option `--help=` incredibly helpful for looking up information about options.

However, while I can find lots of information using e.g. `--help=common` and `--help=separate`, I can't find any section describing `-L` and `-l` for specifying libraries.

Since `-L` and `-l` have been critical for application development for many years, they must be present in some help section.

How can I show help information for `-L` and `-l` using `--help=`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are command-line options for subprocesses, so you need to add `-v` to see them. `gcc -help` says

> (Use '-v --help' to display command line options of sub-processes).

and doing so yields

```
[...]
The following options are language-related:
[...]
  -L                          This option lacks documentation.
```

and then in the linker options,

```
  -l LIBNAME, --library LIBNAME
                              Search for library LIBNAME
  -L DIRECTORY, --library-path DIRECTORY
                              Add DIRECTORY to library search path
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure. `-v --help` doesn't work with a specified type, right? Like `-v --help=common` just to see "common" options of subprocesses.

Comment: Is it possible for `gcc -v --help` just to show options for e.g. `ldd`?

Comment: AFAICT you can’t ask `gcc` to show only the options for `ld`; but if you know you want those, running `ld --help` directly will list them. `--help=` with a sub-type asks for compiler options only (it’s passed to `cc1`).

Comment: Why does `-L` also show up under `--help=separate`, when those options are for the compiler and not the linker? How is it possible to specify `-L` for both simultaneously (and not ambiguously)?

Comment: I don’t know why it shows up there, but it is unambiguous — it only adds directories to the library search path.